# log http traffic in spring boot web application

Tags: spring, http, logging

I have a spring boot web application installed on tomcat7. I am looking for a way to log the http incoming and outcoming requests (header and body).I am looking for something similar to org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor.
Can you help?

Comment: Do you want to log every Http Request and every Http Response, or separate them for example by login/logout, special Request-Mapping etc.. ?

Comment: Use one of the `AbstractRequestLoggingFilter` subclasses to log the requests. The interceptor you are pointing at is for web services (if I'm not mistaken). If you want to enable logging for Spring Web Services you can set `org.springframework.ws.client.MessageTracing` to trace.

Comment: @s.kwiotek  every request/response

Comment: @M. Deinum  Thanks for the info .AbstractRequestLoggingFilter did the work for requests.I need something similar for server responses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could implement your own filter like:

```
@Component
public class SimpleFilter implements Filter {

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        // logic...
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {}

    public void destroy() {}

}
```

This is also a good solution for both of your requirements to intercept requests and response...